# App crash luego de hacer el build release minificado

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

Al hacer el release de mi aplicación de la siguiente manera

```
tns build android --bundle --clean --env.uglify --env.aot --release --key-store-path <path>.jks --key-store-password password --key-store-alias appName --key-store-alias-password password
```

Y el app.graddle con la siguiente configuración

```
android {
...
buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled true

      shrinkResources true

      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
              'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
              'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
...
```

Me genera un archivo apk minificado que al instalar en el dispositivo, no me abre. Me muestra una imagen como la siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si yo configuro **minifyEnabled** y **shrinkResources** en mi *app.gradle* en false, la app corre con normalidad, pero necesito mi apk minificado ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Podrias mirar [ask]??? asi como esta es dificil saber que puede estar pasando. Sin un ejemplo claro, solo se puede conjeturar al respecto

Comment: Listo, ya hice una explicación más detallada del problema para ver si consigo algo de ayuda. Gracias por la respuesta y sugerencia amigo